# React createContext issue in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

So I'm having a very weird issue with React Context + Typescript.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jk69315l0)

In the above example, you can see what I'm trying to do actually work. Essentially I'm managing state with the new useContext method, and it works perfectly.

However, when I try to do this on my box, it cannot seem to find the state values being passed through the useReducer.

```
export function AdminStoreProvider(props: any) {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
// state.isAuth is avail here
// state.user is avail here
const value = { state, dispatch };
// value.state.isAuth is avail here
return (
    /* value does not contain state once applied to the value prop */
    <AdminStore.Provider value={value}>{props.children} 
    </AdminStore.Provider>
   );
}
```

Error message:

```
Type '{ state: { isAuth: boolean; user: string; }; dispatch: 
Dispatch<Actions>; }' is missing the following properties from type 
'IState': isAuth, user
```

Keep in mind the code I'm using is exactly what I'm using on my box, I've even downloaded the code from sandbox and tried running it, and it doesn't work.

I'm using VSCode 1.31

I've managed to deduce that if I change how I create my context from:

```
export const AdminStore = React.createContext(initialState);
```

to

```
export const AdminStore = React.createContext(null);
```

The value property no longer throws that error.

However, now useContext returns an error: state doesn't exist on null. And same if I set defaultState for context to {}.

And of course if I

```
React.createContext();
```

Then TS yells about no defaultValue being provided.

*In sandbox, all 3 versions of creating the context object work fine.*

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It appears `defaultValue` value for  [`React.createContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) is expected to be of type:

```
interface IContextProps {
  state: IState;
  dispatch: ({type}:{type:string}) => void;
}
```

Once `Context` object is created for this type, for example like this:

```
export const AdminStore = React.createContext({} as IContextProps);
```

Provider React component should no longer complain about the error.

Here is the list of changes:

**`admin-store.tsx`**

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { initialState, IState, reducer } from "./reducer";


interface IContextProps {
  state: IState;
  dispatch: ({type}:{type:string}) => void;
}


export const AdminStore = React.createContext({} as IContextProps);

export function AdminStoreProvider(props: any) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return (
    <AdminStore.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</AdminStore.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did remove the error, but now it errors:

`Type '{ state: { isAuth: boolean; user: string; }; dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>; }' is not assignable to type 'IContextProps'.
  Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.
    Type 'Dispatch<Actions>' is not assignable to type '({ type }: { type: string; }) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and '__0' are incompatible.
        Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Actions'.
          Property 'value' is missing in type '{ type: string; }' but required in type 'ILogout'`

Comment: Here is my latest: https://codesandbox.io/s/7jk69315l0

It actually compiles now, but crashes in the browser on: `export function AdminStoreProvider(props: any) {` saying "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Comment: Side note, once I imported Dispatch from react, and then exported  and imported Actions, my main issue was resolved with the warnings and error.

`interface IContextProps {
  state: IState;
  dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>;
}`

was my final interface which worked

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the error: `Type assertion on object literals is forbidden, use a type annotation instead.`

Comment: @bauervision Is the answer as it is complete, or would someone need to add the code from your comment (on Feb 14 at 19:38) in order for it to work? If so, can you please update the answer accordingly so the accepted answer holds the correct code?

Answer (score 15):

My stomach turns when Typescript subdues me where it should be serving me.
In this particular case I really don't care about types, and I solve it this way:

The following works just fine:

```
const ctx = createContext<any>({});
```

Most examples that don't use TS take no parameter at all, and I see no value in adding more code than I need.

Answer (score 14):

I had a fun time with this so I figured I'd share what I came up with.

The `SidebarProps` represent the context's state. Everything else, besides the reducer actions, can essentially be used as is.

Here is a nice article explaining the exact same workaround (Not in TypeScript) : [Mixing Hooks and Context Api](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)

```
import React, { createContext, Dispatch, Reducer, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

interface Actions {
    type: string;
    value: any;
}

interface SidebarProps {
    show: boolean;
    content: JSX.Element | null;
}

interface SidebarProviderProps {
    reducer: Reducer<SidebarProps, Actions>;
    initState: SidebarProps;
}

interface InitContextProps {
    state: SidebarProps;
    dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>;
}

export const SidebarContext = createContext({} as InitContextProps);
export const SidebarProvider: React.FC<SidebarProviderProps> = ({ reducer, initState, children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);
    const value = { state, dispatch };
    return (
        <SidebarContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </SidebarContext.Provider>
    );
};
export const useSidebar = () => useContext(SidebarContext);

const SidebarController: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const initState: SidebarProps = {
        show: false,
        content: null
    };

    const reducer: Reducer<SidebarProps, Actions> = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'setShow':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    show: action.value
                };

            case 'setContent':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    content: action.value
                };

            default:
                return state;
        }
    };

    return (
        <SidebarProvider reducer={reducer} initState={initState}>
            {children}
        </SidebarProvider>
    );
};

export default SidebarController;
```